# Drupal - Showcase a NODE

Tags: drupal, cck, organic-groups

**Showcase content/**

I want to allow users to showcase their content within particular groups.i.o.w choose content they have created and make show particular CCK fields witin a OG.

*Example:*

a

1. user created node X, he then wants
   to show node X to everyone else in
   the group.
2. He clicks on a button in the group,
   called showcse your node, which then
   brings up all the Nodes  that
   theparticular user has created
3. The user then chooses the node, and
   clicks submit.

I would then like to create a view or  block that list all the nodes that has been showcased within a particular group. So I guess it needs to some how reference the group.

Can anyone direct me in the right direction of how this can possible be done?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, maybe have a tag in one of the vocabularies for nodes in the group called "showcased".  Then simply create a view that displays all nodes with that tag?